# Store result of computation in numpy array (instead of creating new one)

Tags: numpy

Suppose I have the code:

```
a, b, c = np.empty((3,)), np.array([1, 2, 3]), np.array([4, 5, 6])
a = b + c
```

What I would like is for the result of b+c to be stored in existing array a. I do not want a new array to be allocated. How can I make this happen in numpy?

Comment: I treat the `out` parameter of `ufunc` as an optimization feature.  Priority is getting the code working and clear.  `numpy` is pretty good at allocating and reusing memory.

Answer (score 2):

```
np.add(b, c, out=a)
```

NumPy ufuncs (and a few other NumPy routines) take an `out` parameter to place the output in.

Answer (score 0):

If your memory is that critical and you don't want to roam around with 3 arrays (a, b and c), you can do :

```
b, c = np.array([1, 2, 3]), np.array([4, 5, 6])
b += c  # does in-place operation, similarly to np.add(b, c, out=b)
```

where `b` is now carrying the result you had in array `a`.